# All the `stargazer()` tables are being put at the end my document

Tags: r, r-markdown, stargazer

Right now im working on a project where I'm making multiple tables using `stargazer()` and they are all getting pushed to the end of the document.

im using the following code chunks:

````
```
  {r mylatextable,results='asis'}
lm2<-lm(x~y)
lm2a<-lm(x~y+y^2+z)
stargazer(lm2,lm2a,align=TRUE)
```
````

and then for the subsequent tables I would use

````
```
{r,results='asis'}
lm3a<-lm(k~r)
lm3b<-lm(k~r+r^2)
stargazer(lm3a,lm3b)
```
````

however when knitting the document together in R markdown I am having all the tables come on the last pages as opposed to having each individual table being within the document.How would I go about having each table where I want it in the document as opposed to having all the tables on the last page?

Comment: Are you knitting to pdf or html?

Comment: @avid_useR im knitting to pdf.